# inline code causes ASP.NET to insert 500 page inside the current page

Tags: asp.net, webforms, custom-errors

I have some code in an .ascx that looks like this:

```
<%
 int a = 0;
 int b = 5;
 int c = b/a;
 %>
```

Throws a 500 error as you would expect (division by 0).

CustomErrors looks like this

```
    <customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
        <error statusCode="500" redirect="/500.aspx" />
    </customErrors>
```

I get a messed up render of the page I'm trying to hit.  Viewing the source, I see half the normal page THEN the 500 page follows it.

```
    <div class="mapTextOverlay" style="width:448px;padding-left:232.96px;">

    [main page abruptly ends here and the 500 page starts]

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head id="Head"><title>
        500
    </title>

    [etc.]
```

So the server transfer is happening in the middle of the page render.

How do I prevent the possibility of a partial-page render in the case of a 500 error?

- This only happens with inline code, if the error is in code-behind the error displays normally.
- Nothing in the code is calling Response.Flush()
- Response.BufferOutput is true
- The code is setting a Response.Filter, but I tried commenting that and it did not fix it

Comment: This isn't normal behavior - the entire page will execute before *any* response is sent to the client. So it can't send you a partial response then send a different one. Are you loading in other pages via AJAX? Seems like your question is missing an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know why this is happening, but the fix turns out to be rather simple.

Put `Response.Clear();` in the `Page_Load()`of the 500 page.

Comment: I think that in the case of inline code, the response is already being constructed with whatever HTML was generated by the page or controls prior to hitting the inline code; so when the custom error page gets invoked, it's just adding to an existing response.